# Asp.net SynchronizationContext locks HttpApplication for async continuations?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

[This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7804363/async-ctp-bug-task-never-completes#comment9513880_7804458) by [Stephen Cleary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary) says this:

> `AspNetSynchronizationContext` is the strangest implementation. It treats `Post` as synchronous rather than asynchronous and **uses a lock to execute its delegates one at a time**.

Similarly, [the article that he wrote on synchronization contexts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx) and linked to in that comment suggests:

> Conceptually, the context of AspNetSynchronizationContext is complex. During the lifetime of an asynchronous page, the context starts with just one thread from the ASP.NET thread pool. After the asynchronous requests have started, the context doesn’t include any threads. As the asynchronous requests complete, the thread pool threads executing their completion routines enter the context. These may be the same threads that initiated the requests but more likely would be whatever threads happen to be free at the time the operations complete.
>
> If multiple operations complete at once **for the same application**, AspNetSynchronizationContext will ensure that they execute one at a time. They may execute on any thread, but that thread will have the identity and culture of the original page.

Digging in reflector seems to validate this as it takes a lock on the `HttpApplication` while invoking any callback.

Locking the app object seems like scary stuff.  So my first question: Does that mean that today, all asynchronous completions for the entire app execute one at a time, even ones that originated from separate requests on separate threads with separate HttpContexts?  Wouldn't this be a huge bottleneck for any apps that make 100% use of async pages (or async controllers in MVC)?  If not, why not?  What am I missing?

Also, in .NET 4.5, it looks like there's a new `AspNetSynchronizationContext`, and the old one is renamed `LegacyAspNetSynchronizationContext` and only used if the new app setting `UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext` is not set.  So question #2: Does the new implementation change this behavior?  Otherwise, I imagine with the new async/await support marshaling completions through the synchronization context, this kind of bottleneck would be noticed much more frequently going forward.

The answer to [this forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-NZ/async/thread/b2e8c51e-2808-46d0-92e9-b825321d0af8) (linked from SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9562836/whats-the-meaning-of-usetaskfriendlysynchronizationcontext)) suggests that something fundamentally changed here, but I want to be clear on what that is and what behaviors have improved, since we have a .NET 4 MVC 3 app which is pretty much 100% async action methods making web service calls.

Comment: I suspect the existing behavior was considered "good enough." Remember that the asynchronous operations themselves are independent; it is only their completion routines (and continuations) that are synchronized. Also, async pages were hard before 4.5; most ASP.NET apps currently out there are synchronous.

Comment: And I haven't had a chance to check out the new ASP.NET synccontext. Just got 4.5 with VS2012RC installed last weekend, in fact! But I'll answer here eventually if no one else does.

Comment: Please do.  You would be one of the most authoritative sources on the topic.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let me answer your first question. In your assumption you didn't consider the fact that separate ASP.NET requests are processed by different HttpApplication objects. HttpApplication objects are stored in pool. Once you request a page, an application object is retrieved from pool and belongs to the request till its completion. So, my answer to your question:

> all asynchronous completions for the entire app execute one at a time, even ones that originated from separate requests on separate threads with separate HttpContexts

is: No, they don't

Separate requests are processed by separate HttpApplication objects, locked HttpApplication will affect only single request.
Synchronization context is a powerful thing that helps developers to synchronize access to shared (in scope of request) resources. That is why all callbacks are executed under lock. Synchronization context is a heart of event-based synchronization pattern.

Comment: Irony is I just realized this this morning on the way to work while pondering http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413585/do-asynchronous-httpapplication-events-wait-until-they-return/11731051#11731051.  Your response about separate HttpApplication per request is absolutely correct.  Thanks for the insight.